# Sharepoint Custom List definition and javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, list-definition

Hey i want to create a list instance with a definition that defines the following columns.

```
-Notice StartDate (DateTime)
-Notice EndDate   (DateTime)
-Notice Message   (Text)
-Notice Colleges  (???)
```

I created the dates and message inside my list def i just have no idea what type should the Colleges column be. I just know it should be a list that represents multiple users.

Also i would like to be able to call a Javascript function to Populate new item inside the list and delete them. Also if i retract the solution how will sharepoint deal with this ? Will items added to the list while the solution is deployed still be there when i redeploy ???

Answer (score 1):

In response to your questions:

- You can make Colleagues a 'Person or Group' column which allows for multiple values. Presumably, you want to render a list of all users from which the user can select? If you're doing this server-side, you could bind against SPWeb.AllUsers or SPWeb.Users depending on your needs. Note that neither of those will return all users in your NT domain if that's what you're after (that is a little more complicated).
- If you want to manipulate SP lists using Javascript, you should look into using the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx).
- If you retract your solution, the list items will remain there.

Comment: Thank you. I would just add that the Field type to reference multiple users is actually "UserMulti" but it still does not let me input more than 1 user for some reason.